# Property not change on two way binding mode with dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have the following dependency property:

```
public bool UndoZoom
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(UndoZoomProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UndoZoomProperty, value); }
        }
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UndoZoom.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UndoZoomProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UndoZoom", typeof(bool), typeof(ZoomBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUndoZoomChanged)));
```

On the callback methods I change this property to false:

```
   private static void OnUndoZoomChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ZoomBehavior zoomBehavior = sender as ZoomBehavior;
        if (zoomBehavior == null || zoomBehavior.UndoZoom == false)
            return;

       //DO SOMETHING... 
        zoomBehavior.UndoZoom = false;

       //ALSO TRY:  zoomBehavior.SetValue(UndoZoomProperty, false);
    }
```

The dependency property changes well, but the property that binding to it not!

The binding look like that :

```
UndoZoom="{Binding MyClass.UndoZoom,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I would like to note that the binding does **work**, when I change the property in the model, the callback is fire, that's mean that the dependency property changes.

I just do not understand why it does not work the other way too, I expect that when I change the dependency property, the property in the model will also change.

I would love help.

Comment: Setting the UndoZoom property in its own PropertyChangedCallback doesn't make sense. The callback is called when the property has changed. You should not set it again there. The code in the callback is only executed when the property value is `true`, then you immediately set it to `false`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you get any binding errors when running the application in your debug message window?

Comment: @Clemens. Why not? I do see that the callback methods knows to be fired again when this assignment is done, so why the binding does not work? I do something before I change it back to false, Is a kind of flag that I need just to do somthing when it is true and then change it back to false.

Comment: Is it meant to be kind of a trigger? You should use a command instead.

Comment: @derape.I wrote that the binding **does work**.

Comment: With respect to the previous comments about changing the property value in the property changed handler, the coercion callback is more suited to doing this. The property changed callback is meant for reacting to a change of value. The Coercion callback is for making sure the value is valid based on the current state which feels more like what you are doing here.

Comment: @Clemens, because some complicated reasons I need to use property to perform it.command can really be a perfect solution, but I can not to perform it.

Comment: Just checked this, and it works for me. From what you've shown here, the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @Clemens, I'm currently checked it on simple demo project, and it does not work for me. You can show what you've done.

Comment: I haven't done anything special, just declared your UndoZoom dependency property in my MainWindow and bound it two-way to an UndoZoom property in a view model class. Then I've set the dependency property in a Button Click handler. It does however not work as you expect when I set the view model property to true. The PropertyChangedCallback resets the property to false, but this change is not transferred back to the view model. So, the VM property stays true. As said initially, you shouldn't be doing this at all. It's the wrong approach.

Comment: @JamesLucas. your comments is the correct one that help me! can you upload it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coercion callback is more suited to doing this. The property changed callback is meant for reacting to a change of value. The Coercion callback is for making sure the value is valid based on the current state which feels more like what you are doing here.